# pysnmp setCmd doesn't appear to set object, but no errors

Tags: python, set, pysnmp

I'm new to SNMP and pysnmp. I've written a quick bit of code to set a few the values for a few MIBs, but it doesn't appear to be working. The OIDs that I am using did work in an old perl script that we no longer use, so I know I have the right ones.

What am I missing? I don't have any more hair to pull out!  :)19

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

from pysnmp.hlapi import * # For SNMP

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
      setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
             CommunityData("myCommunity", mpModel=1),
             UdpTransportTarget(("remotedevice.com",161)),
             ContextData(),
             ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(".1.3.6.1.4.1.4115.1.8.1.10.5.1.0"), Integer(3)) ,
             ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(".1.3.6.1.4.1.4115.1.8.1.10.5.2.0"), OctetString("192.168.1.1")) ,
             ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(".1.3.6.1.4.1.4115.1.8.1.10.5.3.0"), OctetString("backup")) ,
             ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(".1.3.6.1.4.1.4115.1.8.1.10.5.6.0"), Integer(3)) )
)

print(errorIndication)
print(errorStatus)
print(errorIndex)
for bind in varBinds:
    print(bind)
```

output:

```
None
0
0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.4115.1.8.1.10.5.1.0 = 3
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.4115.1.8.1.10.5.2.0 = 192.168.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.4115.1.8.1.10.5.3.0 = backup
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.4115.1.8.1.10.5.6.0 = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the SET command actually succeeded. The output you get is what your SNMP agent @remotedevice.com has reported. So these should be the new values for these OIDs.

What makes you think that the query did not work out? Could it be a concurrently running SNMP manager resetting the values back? Just a wild thought...

BTW, `mpModel=1` means SNMP version 2c. Just in case your SNMP agent prefers any other SNMP version.

Comment: You were correct. The request was working. It turned out to be the device I used to test on was buggy. Changed my target device and everything worked the way that I expected. Thanks for the help!